# Gradient of floor

Tags: floor

I am trying to work out how much my kitchen floor slopes before putting in a flat pack kitchen. The spirit level says it is a 2 degrees slope so how much does it drop over a metre? Appreciate any answers.

Comment: That's a massive tilt. I seriously doubt it's that much. You need a full-length level of high quality (or a rigid straightedge with a shorter level), and you need to reverse it to check for error.

Comment: Tan(theta) x 100 will give you slope as a percent, or cm/m. So a 2 degree slope is 3 cm/m, which is quite a bit.  Typical allowable deflections in building codes are 1/180 (approx 1/3 of a degree) or 1/360, depending on the application.

Answer (score 1):

tan(theta) = rise/run

tan(2 degree) = 0.035

That would be a 3.5cm drop over a 100cm run.

Comment: Thanks for that, sounds about right according to the kitchen bloke who visited

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigonometry if you have access to a reference.  For small angles (less than about 10 degrees), there is a handy approximation that is very close and easy to remember.  If you have the measurements (rise or drop and the distance), the angle in degrees is approximately `rise/run * 400/7`.

In your case, you have the angle and the run, so you can transpose to find the rise (or drop in your case): for 2 degrees and a run of 1 meter, `rise = 2 * 7/400 * 1 meter = .035 meters` or 3.5 cm.